# What's Delphi Gantt/Scheduler component can I use?

Tags: delphi, gantt-chart

I'm currently using DevExpress Scheduler's GanttView in my application, it does what I need except for one thing. My scheduler has multiple resources, and each resource has numerous events. The problem with the DevExpress scheduler is the height of each resource on the screen has to be the same, that means if a resource has 15 events, and another has 1 event, the resource with 1 event end up taking up lots of wasted space.

Is there a scheduler available for Delphi that would adjust the height of each resource according to the number of events in it?

The other requirements are quite simple:

- The time scale should be at 15mins of less
- Events can be drag to adjust start/end time
- Events can be drag to different resources
- Each event can be categories to different colours
- No event linking is necessary
- Events can start at anytime, no need to wait for previous event to finish

Hope I've explained this ok, let me know if you need any clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using eXontrol's exg2antt

http://www.exontrol.com/exg2antt.jsp

It's a COM component instead of native VCL, the layout aspect seems quite flexible, I especially like the combination of a tree grid and gantt chart. The default look is quite dated, but a skin can easily be apply to it.

I did have problem with the TLB file generated causing bad variant type errors, but the developers emailed me back a working solution within 24hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Someone did a run-down on about.com:
http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/aatpplaner.htm
and another:
http://www.sourcecodeonline.com/list?q=gantt_vcl_delphi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the Sad Man Software RAC chart will exactly meets your needs, but I can tell you that I've used the component for 3 years now and the quality of the component is exceptional.